# Java RPC library with capnproto?

Tags: java, roc, capnproto

Currently the capnproto uber-fast library doesn't provide an RPC library, which makes it difficult to replace existing GRPCio (Or other RPC java frameworks). Why the capnproto Java support is currently limited only to serialisation? Are there plans to support a full RPC framework as well ?

Answer (score 4):

We'd love to support RPC in Java and all other languages. However, Sandstorm.io (Cap'n Proto's parent project) is currently seven people and a cat, so we unfortunately don't have the resources internally to build out the parts of Cap'n Proto that we don't immediately need. We rely on volunteers from the community, but so far there hasn't been a volunteer to build RPC in Java. Some day, when Sandstorm gets bigger and we start seeing a lot more Java apps, it will probably make sense for us to build Java RPC ourselves, but I'm not sure how soon that will be.

FWIW, I've heard that a lot of people have had success combining Cap'n Proto serialization with ZeroMQ for transport.

Comment: Are you big enough yet?

Comment: @user1870400 Unfortunately, Sandstorm has not had any paid employees since early 2017, and development has almost completely stopped. However, I'm continuing to develop Cap'n Proto's C++ implementation at my new job at Cloudflare. But, at present, we don't have a need for Java RPC support there, so the situation remains pretty similar: we need outside contributors to work on Java support.